# how to get random datetime of specific date

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a sql query where i need to get datetime of any specific date.
For this i used the following query:-

```
DECLARE @RandomDate datetime

DECLARE @fromDate datetime='2018-04-07'


SELECT @RandomDate= (DATEADD(day, ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, @fromDate, @fromDate) 
* RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 5),DATEADD(second, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 24000, 
@fromDate))) 

SELECT  @RandomDate
```

Here in the above example i want to get datetime of date '2018-04-07' i.e 7 April. But sometime it is showing datetime of 6 april also. How to solve it?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204878/how-to-get-random-datetime-of-current-day-in-sql-server One question - in one site - is enough.

Comment: ok. I will remember next time. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

`CHECKSUM` can return negative as well as positive values and `%` applied to a negative value will produce a negative result. Finally, `DATEADD` is perfectly happy to add a negative number of seconds onto a date and will produce a result earlier than its passed in date argument.

If you want a value strictly in the range 0 - 23999, then do two mods and an addition:

```
((valueToConvert % 24000) + 24000) % 24000
```

(Incidentally - 24000 seems like an odd number to be using here. There are 86400 seconds in a day. Is there a reason why your random time has to fall between midnight and 6:40am?)

Comment: My random time should fall midnight time from 00:00:0 am to  26:59:59PM

Comment: where i have to used this query. If possible kingly write the complete query.